# SparkSubmit launched by Kubernetes Spark Operator stuck with no error details

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

In K8S Spark Operator, submitted job are getting stuck at Java thread, at the following command with no error details:

/opt/tools/Linux/jdk/openjdk1.8.0.332_8.62.0.20_x64/bin/java -cp /opt/spark/conf/:***/opt/spark/jars/* org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit*** --master k8s://https://x.y.z.a:443 --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=IfNotPresent --conf spark.executor.memory=512m --conf spark.driver.memory=512m --conf spark.network.crypto.enabled=true --conf spark.driver.cores=0.100000 --conf spark.io.encryption.enabled=true --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.limit.cores=200m --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.label.version=3.0.1 --conf spark.app.name=sparkimpersonationx42aa8bff --conf spark.kubernetes.submission.waitAppCompletion=false --conf spark.executor.cores=1 --conf spark.authenticate=true --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.label.sparkoperator.k8s.io/launched-by-spark-operator=true --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=abc --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=placeholder:94 --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.label.sparkoperator.k8s.io/**launched-by-spark-operator=true** --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.label.sparkoperator.k8s.io/submission-id=b651fb42-90fd-4675-8e2f-9b4b6e380010 --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.label.sparkoperator.k8s.io/app-name=sparkimpersonationx42aa8bff --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.label.sparkoperator.k8s.io/submission-id=b651fb42-90fd-4675-8e2f-9b4b6e380010 --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=sparkimpersonationx42aa8bff-driver --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark-driver-abc --conf spark.executor.instances=1 --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.label.version=3.0.1 --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.label.sparkoperator.k8s.io/app-name=sparkimpersonationx42aa8bff --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --jars local:///sample-apps/sample-basic-spark-operator/extra-jars/* local:///sample-apps/sample-basic-spark-operator/sample-basic-spark-operator.jar

Comment: If just hanging I would suspect network connection. Check network connectivity.

Comment: Thank you, Issueof sparkSubmit processes getting blocked builds up gradually over 5-6 hours; until then Spark Operator keeps processing submitted Spark Applications successfully. With ~10 java process IDs of above sort get spun up and as they are stuck, Spark Operator does not process any more Spark Applications. I tried to get thread dump of the process ids; that did not give useful information(pasted below for reference). Once I kill these SparkSubmit processes, Spark Operator starts processing the SparkApplications successfully.
INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: State changed, new state:

Answer (score 0):

From the available information, the causes for this can be:

1. The workload pods cannot get scheduled on your k8s nodes. You can check this with `kubectl get pods`, are the pods `Running`?
2. The resource limits have been reached and the pods are unresponsive.
3. The spark-operator itself might not be running. You should check the logs for the operator itself.

That's all I can say from what is available.

Comment: Thank you for reply. This issue of sparkSubmit processes getting blocked builds up gradually over 5-6 hours; until then Spark Operator keeps processing submitted Spark Applications successfully. With ~10 java process IDs of above sort get spun up and as they are stuck, Spark Operator does not process any more Spark Applications. I tried to get thread dump of the process ids; that did not give useful information(pasted below for reference). Once I kill these SparkSubmit processes, Spark Operator starts processing the SparkApplications successfully

Comment: Which kubernetes version are you running? I know of instances of `JVM` memory management issues in Kubernetes v1.21 for sure, on an Ubuntu 18.04 based node.
And as you describe the problem to "build up", it surely sounds like a memory leak. You can ensure this by monitoring the resource usage of your sparkSubmit processes. And try upgrading your node OS version, which should most definitely fix this.

Comment: We are not looking at the role of K8S version or the worker node OS; mainly because same Spark Operator(2.4.x version) runs stable with CRD v1beta1 schema. As soon as we include v1beta2 schema with Storage: v1beta2; the issue crops up.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth looking into; the difference between the schema versions? Also, if you're running CRD version beta, you're definitely k8s v1.21 or earlier, because v1.22 mandates CRDs to be updated to v1, stable.

Answer (score 0):

Run below command to see the list of spark apps. You will also see the status of the application in the output.

```
kubectl get sparkapplications -n <namespace>
NAME            STATUS    ATTEMPTS   START                  FINISH       AGE
myapp           RUNNING   1          2023-06-06T10:47:16Z   <no value>   85m
```

. If the above output status is anything other than running, then you can select that spark app and describe it

```
kubectl describe sparkapplications -n <namespace> myapp
```

If your app is in running state just check the logs of the driver and executor pods.

Comment: Can you provide some details - like: Is 'sparkapplications' a Kubernetes Deployment in this context?